# What are the specific id's required for the fulfillment cancel call in the shopify API?

Tags: shopify

I've written an automated system to automatically fulfill items in shopify via the API from data received from a fulfillment center but would like to build a tool to "undo" fulfillment should there be a problem but I can't seem to get the API to respond and the documentation is fuzzy as to which id's are required..

I assume the first #id is the order id and the second the item but I've tried all the id's from the order/fulfillment (line item ids, item_id, etc) and I'm still getting a `{"errors":"Not Found"}` from POST CURL call.

Am I using the wrong id? or is there some other reason work?

Here's the url Im hitting:

```
https://{API_KEY}:{API_PASS}@{my_store}.myshopify.com/admin/orders/{order_id}/fulfillments/{some_id?}/cancel.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The first ID is the order ID, as defined in the `order_id` parameter on the fulfillment.

The second ID is the fulfillment ID, which is defined in the `id` parameter on the fulfillment.

Assuming you have a fulfillment that looks like this:

```
"fulfillment": {
    "created_at": "2012-10-16T11:31:17-04:00",
    "id": 255858046,
    "order_id": 450789469,
    "service": "manual",
    "status": "pending",
    "tracking_company": null,
    "tracking_number": "1Z2345",
    "tracking_url": "http://www.google.com/search?q=1Z2345",
    "updated_at": "2012-10-16T11:31:17-04:00",
    "receipt": {
      "testcase": true,
      "authorization": "123456"
    }
}
```

Your POST URL should look like this:

```
/admin/orders/450789469/fulfillments/255858046/cancel.json
```